# how to show cholesky decomposition complexity?

Tags: matrices, computational-complexity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the cost of Cholesky decomposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217738/how-to-calculate-the-cost-of-cholesky-decomposition)

so far i see that for matrix A = L*L^T : (A = a1, a2, a3, a4 matrix)

FOR lower triangular matrix L = l11, 0, L21, L22 (l11 is scalar)

i got that a1 = l_11^2 this is 1 flop | a2 = l11*L21^T this requires n-1 flops ... this gets ugly later when Schur complement is appearing

Can anyone show how i should get n^3/3 complexity/flops when doing Cholesky decomposition on A???

Comment: [Someone else from your class?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217738/how-to-calculate-the-cost-of-cholesky-decomposition)

Comment: I guess i do not get some ideas about this decomposition, it should not be hard if i get it. First of all when i am asked to calculate the complexity of Cholesky decomposition of A, should i consider that A matrix is given, so that l11, L12, amd L21 are known complexity. The only part that i have to do is the recursive part right? I am new to this concept and little confused, if someone can explain the idea better