# Are all symmetric matrices with positive eigenvalues a product of a matrix and its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an $m \times n$ matrix $A$, it's easy to show that the matrix products $B = A^TA$ and $C = AA^T$ are both symmetric. I was wondering if any symmetric matrix **with positive eigenvalues** could be expressed as the product of some matrix and its transpose?

Note: It's obvious that if the eigenvalues are not all positive then this cannot be the case, as $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ both have to be positive semidefinite. However this is all I can think of regarding this problem.

Answer (score 15):

Nevermind, I just got this. I'll leave my answer up in case anyone else finds it useful.

Any symmetric matrix $A$ has to be orthogonally diagonalisable, that is, $A = PDP^T$ for some diagonal matrix $D$ and orthogonal matrix $P$. In this case by the diagonalisation theorem, the diagonal values of $D$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, all of which are given to be $\geq 0$. Therefore, one can "square-root" $D$ as $D = M^2$, where $M$ is a diagonal matrix with the square roots of the diagonal values of $D$ on its diagonal, that is, $m_{ii} = \sqrt{d_{ii}}$ and $m_{ij} = 0$ if $j \neq i$. Therefore:

$$
A = PM^2P^T = (PM)(MP^T) = (PM)(M^TP^T) = (PM)(PM)^T
$$

Comment: Your answer is perfectly correct. But there is a more direct way (and more efficient on the algorithmic point of view): see my answer.

Comment: Simply a complement to your last line: 
$A = PM^2P^T = (PMP^T)(PMP^T) = (PMP^T)^2$, which also  expresses $A$ as the product of a matrix and its transpose. The matrix 
$A^{1/2}:=PMP^T$ is the (unique) positive square root of $A$. All this continues to hold if $A$ is merely positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 9):

A direct answer is that, if a matrix is symmetric and has $>0$ eigenvalues, thus is a symmetric positive definite matrix, it has a **Cholesky decomposition** $A=C^TC$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition), with an upper triangular $C$.

Comment: That's interesting, I hadn't heard of that However my problem with that is that it assumes the proof of another theorem. Is there simple(-ish) proof of the existence of a Cholesky decomposition for any symmetric matrix?

Comment: You must have all positive eigenvalues for that.

Comment: sorry, you are correct, I meant for any symmetric matrix with positive eigenvalues. Is there a relatively simple proof?

Comment: There's a constructive, "if and only if" proof of Cholesky, @Blue; you might want to look it up.

Comment: @Bluefire: I think you can use Gram-Schmidt for the corresponding inner product to find a basis showing that a positive-definite matrix is of the form $PAP^T$ for diagonal $A$ and triangular $P$, and then you can just take $C=P\sqrt A$. But I did not check it.

Comment: Constructive proof of the existence of the Cholesky factorization: the [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2284425/65548) shows that $A=B^TB$ for some matrix $B$ (not necessarily triangular). Now take a QR factorization of $B$.

Comment: Do you realize that you need more underlying steps to prove Cholesky decomposition than ones present in OP's answer, right?

Comment: @Danijel Yes, for the proof, you are right. I was thinking, without having been explicit enough, to the  **computational complexity** of Cholesky decomposition which is rather low : $\dfrac13n^3$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/217738) for an operation on matrices.

Comment: @Danijel, in practice, Cholesky is way cheaper to do than eigendecomposition, so it is good to have it here.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Indeed it is. I've got an impression that OP was asking for a proof, not for a technique to make an explicit construction.