# What's the number of operations for the Gauss Jordan elimination method and the Cholesky method?

Tags: numerical-calculus

I scoured through the internet looking for an answer on how many operations it would take to solve a system of linear equations using these two methods to no avail.

Is there a documentation of some kind where I can look up the number of operations it would take for these two methods i.e. number of additions/multiplications/divisions with proof?

Comment: Does [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/counting-operations-in-gaussian-elimination) not give the answer for G-J?

Comment: And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217738/how-to-calculate-the-cost-of-cholesky-decomposition) for Cholesky?

Comment: The first link is proof of the Gauss elimination, not quite Gauss-Jordan.
The second one is proof about some flops of some kind which I have no clue what it means. I'm more looking for number of additions/multiplications required.

Comment: A FLOP is a floating-point operation, i.e. standard arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer (without Cholesky):

[image]